# Javascript Object exists but when I call a key returns undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am not asking a question because I finally solved it, but I will publish it since I spent more han 3 hours trying to figure it out.

**SITUATION**

I am developing a Chrome Extension and want to allow the user to change Chrome settings through the "options.html" page.

The extension loads the Current Configuration as an Object `options.js`:

```js
let myConfiguration = new Object()
myConfiguration = getCurrentConfig()
```

If I call my variable `myConfiguration` within my `options.js`, I get an empty Object:

```js
console.log(myConfiguration)
// Output: {}
```

If I call my variable from devtools I get the Object:

```js
console.log(myConfiguration)
// Output: {key1: value1, key2: value2,...}
```

This drove me nuts. See answer below.

Comment: The console is async.  This is a confusing concept.  But essentially when you console log an object, your logging a reference.  When your browser gets around to showing the log, it evaluates the contents of the object at that point, which is at minimum a full event loop later. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392650/3389900

Comment: A hint how structure this question. Remove the solution part and put it in an answer instead. You can answer your own questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow dear @Vitrvm, please just ask your question and remove the solution part.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will fix the question/answer this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The problem is that when I call the variable from the `options.js` file it still has not been assigned its value. But when I check the console on devtools my variable has an assigned value.

The solution is to call the function that assigns the variable its value from a new "js" file and place that file before de body tag on the `options.html` page.

I hope this helps somebody from spending 3 hours playing around with the javascript code.